# ASP Gridview MaxLength

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, boundfield

I have a gridview using `<asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="COMMENTS" />`, I would like to only show the first 20 characters in the Commemnt column when the gridview gets populated. Is there way to accomplish this in VB? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using the `RowDataBound` event in codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Gridview1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowDataBound
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
            ' assuming the comments column is the first column '
            If e.Row.Cells(0).Text.Length > 20 Then
                e.Row.Cells(0).Text = e.Row.Cells(0).Text.Substring(0, 20)
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Note that you can access the text on this way only with `BoundFields`. With `TemplateFields` you need to use `FindControl` to get a reference of your controls(f.e. a `TextBox`).

If you would use a `TemplateField` you could also limit the text on the aspx markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commnents">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtID"  
         MaxLength="20" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comments") %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: The Comment column is on the 7th column.

Comment: @g_shockTan: Since `GridViewRow.Cells` returns a `TableCellCollection` with an (zero-based)indexer, you can get the correct TableCell via `e.Row.Cells(6)` then.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length. Even when I changed it to the proper column number.

Comment: @g_shockTan: Have you used my code above with the `If` clause around?

Comment: Thanks. That was wierd. I thought I copied and pasted everything including the If statement, but it was missing. It works now, but would like to add a ..... at the end to show more comments are available.

Comment: @Time Schmelter. Thank you Tim. You are the man. It works and looks perfect. Consider question as resolved.